# Stop excel (or VBA) rounding decimals

Tags: vba, excel, format, currency

I have a VBA macro doing a few operations on cells. For some reason, some of them are rounded to two decimals whereas I want the whole number (5 decimals). I get 0,13 instead of 0,1319:

```
Cells(rowWhere2Write + 2, 4).Value = Worksheets(originalSheet.Name).Cells(r, "AA").Value2 - Cells(rowWhere2Write + 4, 11)
```

In Worksheets(originalSheet.Name).Cells(r, "AA").Value2 I hace this value: 0,1319 € (yes, it's currency formatted even though I'm only interested in 0,1319).

Why is it rounding it to two decimals? How can I get 4-5 decimals instead of two?

Is there a way to get the 5 decimals and format my new cell with € currency as well? So far I've tried but I was getting the number truncated to two decimals as well.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use `Value2` in all cases instead of `Value` (or omitting it) and then assign the `Numberformat` you want to the cell.

Comment: I've tried this:

Cells(rowWhere2Write + 2, 4).NumberFormat = "0.00000"
Cells(rowWhere2Write + 2, 4).Value2 = Worksheets(originalSheet.Name).Cells(r, "AA").Value2 - Cells(rowWhere2Write + 4, 11).Value2

But I only get 0,13000, can't get 0,1319. Changing the order of instructions takes me to the same result. Cells(rowWhere2Write + 2, 4).Value also same result. What ese can I try?

Comment: What are the values of the two cells exactly?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Turns out there was a minus operation for the exact value missing that was making the cell to be exactly 0,13.. What a coincidence lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is a question of NumberFormat... 
Try selection.NumberFormat=""

If the € is important to you, try selection.NumberFormat="0.00????€" (more ? if you like)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Check the comment below, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Either your cell contains 0.13 and you need to change the code that gave this, or it contains 0.1319 but shows 0.13 and selection.NumberFormat="0.00????€"  will work...

Comment: Ah, I got it. Turns out there was a minus operation for the exact value missing that was making the cell to be exactly 0,13.. What a coincidence lol. Thanks